# Secure VMs on own cluster using Openstack and Ubuntu?

Tags: server, cloud, virtualization

I recently got my hands on a bunch of old servers at work. The idea is to be able to deploy VMs across the cluster of machines and hand them out to people at my organization whenever they need a domain name and small server for project.example.com.

Openstack seems to be a good way to achieve this. I can spin up the equivalent of an EC2 instance and give the info to ssh to it to individuals, but I have 2 questions, since I am very new to this cloud computing thing:

1. How would I set up the network so that an instance at project1.example.com is accessible from the outside?
2. What do I have to do to ensure security across instances? For example, I wish to ensure that a person issued project1.example.com can't mess with project2.example.com.
3. How would juju, puppet, chef etc factor into this?

Thank you for your answers, I know that this is a really broad question but would appreciate any pointers you could share.